# Display scale at 1,5 or above unusable since upgrade to 17.04

Tags: unity, display, display-resolution, scaling, 17.04

In **System Settings > Displays** the setting "*Scale for menu and title bars*" at 1,5 was perfect with Ubuntu 16.10 but now since the upgrade to 17.04 the scale is crazy too high !.

In fact, the four first scales (1 / 1,12 / 1,25 and 1,38) are OK but starting with 1,5 and above everything is too big (unusable in fact).

In the two screen shots here below you can see *"the big difference between **1,38** and the next step which is **1,5**"*.

**The first screen shot is with scale 1,38**. Everything looks normal. The size of the window is "normal" and behind it the wallpaper image is visible. 
[image: scale 1,38]

**The second screen shot is with scale 1,5** (the next step after 1,38). As you can see the window is crazy big. So large that we no longer see the wallpaper behind it

[image: scale 1,50]

My Laptop Built-in Display is FHD (1920 x 1080) with Intel HD Graphics 620 and Ubuntu 17.04 64 bits.

This problem (sudden abnormal scale increase between 1,38 and 1,5) was already present in the Ubuntu 17.04 beta release in February.

Why this big difference between 1,38 and 1,5 and how can I scale correctly on a full HD screen without adapting each application individually ?

Update : I made an upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 on another laptop (also Full HD) and I see the same problem. As from 1,5 the display scale is not correct. So it is clearly a new bug since 17.04. Who has the same problem ?

Comment: Similar question with an answer: [Having trouble with HiDPI scaling in Zesty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904594/having-trouble-with-hidpi-scaling-in-zesty)